# Empty AppCenter

Tags: appcenter

just installed my third machine with Elementary OS but AppCenter results are blank when searching or following categories. Wifi connection is fine - I've tried apt-get remove --purge and reinstalling but it's still blank. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be:

After removing appcenter reboot your computer.

Then install appcenter again (do not forget `sudo apt-get update` after installing).

If not solved try rebooting again after `sudo apt-get update` and check if this last reboot solved the problem.

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1615270) on high priority and with a $50 bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If you run AppCenter without running `sudo apt update` at least one time, it shows up empty. As you might have guessed, run `sudo apt update` and then open up AppCenter and things should work.

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1615270) on high importance and with a $30 bounty.